# Read raw http message in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http, httpresponse

I'm sending an http request using the http.request function, and I would like to read the whole http response like text; that is, the raw http protocol text. Is it possible? I've written the below code but it's not working.

```
// Set up the request
console.log('Sending request');
var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    console.log('Response statusCode: ' + res.statusCode);
//    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
//        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
//    });
//    res.on('end', function() {});
});

post_req.on('socket', function (socket) {
    var response = "";
    socket.on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log(chunk);
    });
});

// post the data
post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.end();
```

Comment: Maybe use another node module could help you, I'm not sure. For instance the `request` module is much better than the basic `http`. https://github.com/mikeal/request

Comment: [What do you need the raw text for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 4):

If you want access to the raw http message, I'd suggest using the [net module](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) instead, and writing the request yourself. Something like this for a simple GET request:

```
var net = require('net');

var host = 'stackoverflow.com',
    port = 80,
    socket = net.connect(port, host, function() {

    var request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host + "\r\n\r\n",
        rawResponse = "";

    // send http request:
    socket.end(request);

    // assume utf-8 encoding:
    socket.setEncoding('utf-8');

    // collect raw http message:
    socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
        rawResponse += chunk;
    });
    socket.on('end', function(){
        console.log(rawResponse);
    });


});
```

For a POST request sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, you could write the request using something like:

```
function writePOSTRequest (data, host, path) {
    return "POST " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
            "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" +
            "Content-Length: " + Buffer.byteLength(data) + "\r\n\r\n" +
            data + "\r\n\r\n";

}

var data = "name1=value1&name2=value2",
    request = writePOSTRequest(data, host, "/path/to/resource");
```

where I'm using [Buffer.byteLength](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding) because `Content-Length` requires the length in bytes, not in characters. Also, remember that `data` must be URL encoded.

If you don't know much about the format of HTTP messages, then this is a decent place to start:

http://jmarshall.com/easy/http/

Also, if you don't know what the encoding of the response will be then you'll have to parse the headers first to find out, but [UTF-8 is by far the most common](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/character_encoding/all) so it's a pretty safe bet.

Answer (score 1):

Streams2 and Streams1 not always able to inter-operate well, see "problem: streams1 and streams2 duality" in [this video](http://strongloop.com/developers/videos/#whats-new-in-nodejs-v012).

I tried to listen data at a bit lower level than streams and this code prints raw http response with headers for me:

```
var http = require('http');
var raw = '';

console.log('Sending request');
var req = http.request({host: 'stackoverflow.com'}, function(res) {
  watch(res, 'res');
  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log(raw);
  });
  res.on('data', function(data) {
    // if we don't attach 'data' handler here 'end' is not called
  });
});


req.on('socket', function (socket) {
  socket.resume();
  var oldOndata = socket.ondata;
  socket.ondata = function(buf, start, end) {
    raw += buf.slice(start, end).toString();
    oldOndata.call(socket, buf, start, end);
  };
});

req.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these kind of tools are allowed in your environment, you could run up an HTTP debug proxy such as Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/, which enables you to inspect the HTTP calls and responses.