# How can I read the raw HTTP response in a subpath with node?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get a malformed HTTP response using node. Since the response is malformed, I cannot use `request` normally (it would give the `HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT` error)

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23543522/1748450 I can get the raw HTTP response using the `net` module like so:

```
var net = require('net');

var host = '192.168.1.1',
    port = 80,
    socket = net.connect(port, host, function() {

    var request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host + "\r\n\r\n",
        rawResponse = "";

    // send http request:
    socket.end(request);

    // assume utf-8 encoding:
    socket.setEncoding('utf-8');

    // collect raw http message:
    socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
        rawResponse += chunk;
    });
    socket.on('end', function(){
        console.log(rawResponse);
    });
});
```

However, this only works with getting the response from the host's root page (`192.168.1.1`). The page I'm trying to get the response from is actually `192.168.1.1/admin/landingpage.fwd`.

If I try to edit `host` to that URL then I get this error:

```
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 192.168.1.1/admin/landingpage.fwd
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '192.168.1.1/admin/landingpage.fwd'
}
```

Is this possible to fetch this using the `net` module in the above example?

If not possible, what other way can I use to get the raw HTTP response from that URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expressjs raw body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920208/expressjs-raw-body)

Comment: no, I'm not using express, and this is a one-off script, not something about request handling on the server side

Comment: Why not just put the path in your http request as in: `var request = "GET /admin/landingpage.fwd HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host + "\r\n\r\n",`?  That's where the path goes in an http request.

Comment: @jfriend00 that solved it, thanks so much! You can make an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the path in your http request as in:

```
var request = "GET /admin/landingpage.fwd HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host + "\r\n\r\n",?
```

That's where the path goes in an http request.